# What does having a basepoint buy us in algebraic topology?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

This may be a vague quesion.

I am confused between the basepointed case and non-basepointed case in algebraic topology.
Is there any convenience in base pointed case?
For example, it leads to the definition of smash product, which is left adjoint to the functor $Map(X,-)$ (here maps are preserving base point). In the non-basepointed case, the left adjoint will be the product.
Is there any thing more behind it?

Thank you so much!

Comment: I think some notions may not make sense without base points. For example if your space is not path connected then the fundamental group is not well defined without first fixing a base point.

Comment: It turns the fundamental group into a functor (of course the fundamental groupoid makes sense without a base point). We also gain an initial object and the wedge product becomes the new coproduct, instead of disjoint union.

Comment: Thanks! It is needed to define the fundamental groups.

Comment: ... as well as higher homotopy groups.

Comment: See my answer to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/40945/compelling-evidence-that-two-basepoints-are-better-than-one for looking for more freedom from the single base point view.  There are also strict higher homotopy groupoids.

Answer (score 1):

Without a specified basepoint, it makes it difficult to define the fundamental group or higher homotopy groups. In particular, loops that are *freely* homotopic needn't be distinct in $\pi_1(X,x_0)$; in fact, elements of $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ are freely homotopic iff they're conjugate in the group. So if we forget our basepoint, we lose our group structure. Higher (basepointed) homotopy groups are abelian, so this issue is no longer an issue; two maps $S^n \to X$ (that both preserve a chosen basepoint in $S^n$ and $X$) are basepoint-homotopic iff they're freely homotpic. But the most natural way of defining a sum of two elements - collapsing the equator of $S^n$ and composing with the map $f_1 \wedge f_2: S^n \wedge S^n \to X$ - requires that we've chosen a basepoint of $S^n$ in the first place.

As Ronnie Brown comments above, there's certainly a way to work with more than one basepoint, or without a basepoint at all; the [MO question he links](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/40945/compelling-evidence-that-two-basepoints-are-better-than-one) is helpful for this perspective.